# How is this an example of a catch-22?

Tags: fallacies, paradox

This was given as an example of a catch-22:

[image]

How is the graphic on the right an example of a catch-22? “If you don’t love yourself, how can you love anyone else?” “If no one loves you, how can you love yourself?” What does that even mean?

Comment: This is really a question for an English literature group. A Catch-22 is not a philosophical concept.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I think the question is about how love for oneself is related to loving somebody else and being loved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ill-framed.

Either the top statement needs to be

> If you don’t love yourself, how can anyone else love you?

or else the bottom one

> If you love no one, how can you love yourself?

This would be logically framed as two different Catch-22, since both hypothesize that you need one type of love to get another, and the other to get the first.

It might be easily attacked on the grounds the one or the other requirement is false, but not on grounds of illogicity.